# asp.net get path page folder url

Tags: asp.net, url, path

I have the following url:

```
localhost:1088/Web_Market/A/Sport.aspx
```

It is stored in a string, as below:

```
string str = "localhost:1088/Web_Market/A/Sport.aspx"
```

How can I edit the string so it returns the following?

```
localhost:1088/Web_Market/A/
```

The full path without the `Sport.aspx`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use below code

```
Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Substring(0, Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.LastIndexOf('/') + 1);
```

This will find substring until the last occurance of "/", which will fetch the URL upto what you needed.

Comment: @DineshPrajapati that's better :)

Comment: i did give my feedback , they say:
Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score

Comment: You can click on tick icon, which will mark it as answer. You can find that icon below down arrow.

Comment: @Abrahemhajhle accepting the answer will also give you a reputation boost, so you can work towards being able to upvote! See more here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation

Comment: I get it now, done :)
it first i dont know how its work, but now i know thanks to you guys